# Promise returns undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript, api, promise, subscribe

I need to retrieve the result of my Api call outside the promise but the value I get is undefined.

In OrderService :

```
public async getOrderPrice(device: string) : Promise<any> {
    this.urlOrderPrice = this.urlOrderPrice.replace("device", device);
    return await this.http.get(this.urlOrderPrice).toPromise();
  }
```

In OrderDetailsComponent :

```
 public orderPrice: any;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrder()?.then(data => { this.orderPrice = data; console.log(this.orderPrice) });
 }

private async getOrder() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    let order;
    if (id != null) {
       order = this.orderService.getOrderPrice(id).then((result) => {
        return result.results[Object.keys(result.results)[0]].val;
      });  
    }
    return order;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `getOrder()` when your `id==null`, then returned order is `undefined`

also remove extra await from rest call

```
public async getOrderPrice(device: string) : Promise<any> {
    this.urlOrderPrice = this.urlOrderPrice.replace("device", device);
    return this.http.get(this.urlOrderPrice).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: yes but the returned value is also undefined when id is not null

Comment: Who knows what you have here `return result.results[Object.keys(result.results)[0]].val;` You dont have to use typescript since you are not using any type control whatsoverer.

Comment: This corresponds to the price of the order

Comment: sure, which is probably undefined. But who knows

Comment: this corresponds more precisely to part of the json response returned by the api call

Comment: Which I dont see nor I know what is actually undefined where.

Comment: the value that is undefined is the one returned by the getOrder() function in the OrderDetails component. When I print this value in the promise it is not undefined but outside it is undefined.

Comment: I thought it is easier to just include actual response... but what do I know.